# how to cut txt with hash in perl?

Tags: perl, hash, text-files

I'm new in perl and I'm facing  problem with process a txt file,
it worried me for several days.I hope someone could give me a hand.
here is the txt:

```
AA=a1.png,a2.png,a3.png,b1.png,b2.png,b3.png,fend.png
FF=k1.png,k2.png,k3.png,l1.png,l2.bmp,l3.png
OO=p1.png,y1.png,ul23.bmp
ZZ=i1.png,j1.png
```

I wanna it becomes:

```
AA=a1.png,a2.png,a3.png
AA=b1.png,b2.png,b3.png
FF=k1.png,k2.png,k3.png
FF=l1.png,l2.bmp,l3.png
OO=p1.png
OO=y1.png
ZZ=i1.png
ZZ=j1.png
```

that's to say,I need truncate the last kind pictures ,and keep the first two kinds of pics in a 1 to 1 format.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the names literally `a1.png`, `y2.png`, and so forth? What happened to `fend.png`?

Comment: only the number part auto increment. The pictures named like `a1.png,a2.png,a3.png` have a commonly part . I only need the first two kinds pictures

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This site generally is for help with malfunctioning code, this almost always means that we would like to see some of your attempted solutions. SO is not a "please write this code for me" site. Please read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

```
my $data = <<'EOD'
AA=a1.png,a2.png,a3.png,b1.png,b2.png,b3.png,fend.png
FF=k1.png,k2.png,k3.png,l1.png,l2.bmp,l3.png
OO=p1.png,y1.png,ul23.bmp
ZZ=i1.png,j1.png
EOD
;

my $last_letter = "";
my $newline = "";
foreach my $line (split(/\n/, $data)) {
    my ($var, $vals) = split("=", $line);
    foreach my $val (split(",", $vals)) {
        $val =~ /^(.)(\d+\..+)$/;
        next unless ($1 && $2);
        if ($last_letter eq $1) {
            print ",";
        } else {
            print "$newline$var=";
            $newline = "\n";
            $last_letter = $1;
        }
        print $val;
    }
}
print "\n";
```

Result:

```
AA=a1.png,a2.png,a3.png
AA=b1.png,b2.png,b3.png
FF=k1.png,k2.png,k3.png
FF=l1.png,l2.bmp,l3.png
OO=p1.png
OO=y1.png
ZZ=i1.png
ZZ=j1.png
```